# MySQL Regexp where like value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to match a numeric value that is purely numbers to another value in my database that is the same numbers but has symbols etc (it's phone numbers).

How can I get MySQL to only match the regexp of the mainNumber column (which has symbols etc in it) to my value (just numbers)?

Below is my code:

```
$SQL = "SELECT entities.name
        FROM entities_main_numbers
           LEFT JOIN entities ON entities.id = entities_main_numbers.entityId
        WHERE mainNumber = ?
        LIMIT 1";
```

---

E.g. +44 (0)800 123 123 to match against 440800123123

Comment: can you show exact examples?

Comment: is +44 coming from the user input or thats whats in the db?

Comment: It would be best if you have a column in the database for the cleaned-up version; even if you manage to sanitize on-the-fly, you lose any chance you had of using an index.

Comment: you can match the string from right 9 chars with REPLACE(val, ' ' ,'')

Answer (score 2):

**MYSQL SOLUTION**

you can use mulitple replace statements

```
 WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(mainNumber, '+', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''), ' ', '') = $targetNum
```

very ugly but it works. replaces `('+', ' ', '(', ')')` with `''`

this will convert  this number `+44 (0)800 123 123` to this number `440800123123`
making your statement true if `$targetNum = 440800123123`

**OR PHP SOLUTION**

PHP

```
 $targetNum = preg_replace('/(\d\d)(\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)/', '+$1 ($2)$3 $4 $5', $targetNum);

 // will convert 440800123123 to +44 (0)800 123 123
 // essentially matching the way mainNumber is stored
```

SQL

```
 WHERE mainNumber = $targetNum
```

might be a better solution because it's less taxing on the database

Answer (score 1):

You can be creative and match the 9 digits from the right after getting rid of the spaces, but if the full number is needed you can place few more recursive calls to `REPLACE` eliminating the `() and +`

```
mainnumber = RIGHT(REPLACE('+44 (0)800 123 123', ' ', ''), 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

very ugly, but if you just want to use built in functions, you can use a chain of `REPLACE` to filter out any characters you dont want.
eg:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        entities.name," ","")
      ,"+","")
    ,"(","")
  ,")","") FROM entities_main_numbers;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an MySQL-expert, but you could probably create a function that takes the numeric value. e.g. '440800123123' and transforms it into a regex like

```
'\D*4\D*4\D*0\D*8\D*0\D*0\D*1\D*2\D*3\D*1\D*2\D*3\D*'
```

(`\D` <=> `[^0-9]` in case this is not defined in MySQL)

This you could use with the normal REGEXP-command...